# Como fazer uma rota com mais de 25 pontos no API do Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocalização

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que para fazer uma funcionalidade, preciso marcar paragens de ônibus e traçar a rota pro ônibus.

Tenho todas as paragens em um array, cada uma com a respetiva latitude e longitude. Com o uso da api da google consigo fazer absolutamente tudo o que eu queria, a rota é traçada corretamente e passa pelos respetivos pontos (paragens), porém **têm um limite**.. Se a minha carreira tiver mais que **25** paragens **(waypoints)**, já não é possível traçar a rota com a utilização de waypoints.

Existe alguma solução para o meu problema?

```
/* Inicio e fim da rota */
    var start = busStopList[0].position;
    var end = busStopList[busStopList.length - 1].position;

    /* Array que vai armazenar todos os waypoints */
    var waypts = []
    
    busStopList.forEach(value => {
        /* Inserir no array um objeto com a localização da paragem */
        waypts.push({location: value.position})
    })
    
    /* Eliminar o primeiro e o ultimo item do array */
    waypts.splice(0, 1)
    waypts.splice(waypts.length - 1, 1)

    /* Configs do request */
    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        waypoints: waypts,
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    };
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Achei essa resposta no stackoverflow em inglês https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779886/exceed-23-waypoint-per-request-limit-on-google-directions-api-business-work-lev#:~:text=Individual%20directions%20requests%20may%20contain,waypoints%20allowed%20in%20each%20request. Não consigo testar aqui se elas funcionam.

Comment: Ajudou muito, de verdade. Obrigado